# Distribution of reaction times in (typical organic) chemistry

Tags: organic-chemistry

Is there any research on how reported reaction times are distributed (in typical organic chemistry)?

I feel like I remember that there was a paper/talk discussing this, finding that there was a steep drop around 10-14 h (since one would then have to setup the reaction very late or come in very early for workup - to avoid staying in the lab in the midst of the night), but right now I cannot find anything on the topic.

Comment: 16 hours probably means "I set it up before leaving and found that it was done when I came back the next morning.", doesn't it? ;)

Comment: I guess so! I remember a total synthesis a few years ago, where one of the steps would have 200+ hours... Probably setup before going on vacation for Christmas/New Year's ;)

Comment: Also, another view is that if it isn't done overnight, the reaction does not work.  Your question needs a better specification.

Comment: I do most of reaction overnight, sometime i wake up late in the morning, and time exceed more than 12 hours but i always mention it as overnight. This doesn't make any difference, I have seen same time of reaction in different papers having different reaction times.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't really about a chemistry concept. It's really asking about studies on the behaviour of organic chemists.

Comment: @bon, in my opinion the question is really important, I am also curious to know how reaction time is defined ,

Comment: Why is it important? Reaction time is presumably defined as the time between putting the reactants in the reaction vessel and stopping the reaction by quenching it/removing the contents etc.

Comment: @bon, how you define, stirred overnight ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: A professor in Munich once said: ‘There are only three reaction times. 5 minutes, i.e. you set it up and then you work it up; 2 hours, i.e. over lunch break and 16 hours i.e. over night.’ However, his analysis is skewed: It forgot 70 hours (over the week-end).